Locally Lipschitz continuity of the Fourier transform of $L^1$ function
Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$. It is very famous that $\xi\mapsto \mathcal{F}f(\xi)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^d$, where $\mathcal{F}f$ is the Fourier transform of $f$.
My question is the following: Can we improve the above claim? For example, can we expect that $\mathcal{F}f$ is locally Lipschitz continuous, or more weakly, locally Holder continuous?

No, this is not true in general. Consider, for example, the function $1/|x|^{d+s}$ for $s \in (0,1)$, which can suitably be interpreted as a tempered distribution $u_s \in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that $\mathcal{F}(u_s)(\xi) = |\xi|^s$ (see e.g. Theorem 2.4.6 in Grafakos' Classical Fourier Analysis); more precisely, the distribution is given by
\begin{equation}
\langle u_s,\phi \rangle := c(d,s)\int_{|x|>1} \phi(x)\frac{1}{|x|^{d+s}}\,dx+c(d,s)\int_{|x| \leq 1} (\phi(x)-\phi(0))\frac{1}{|x|^{d+s}}\,dx + b(d,s)\phi(0)
\end{equation}
for all $\phi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and suitable constants $c(d,s)$ and $b(d,s)$. Since $u_s$ differs from the integrable function $\tilde{u}_s(x):=c(d,s)\min\{1,1/|x|^{d+s}\}$ only by a compactly supported distribution, the Paley-Wiener theorem shows that
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}(\tilde{u}_s)(\xi) = |\xi|^s + \varphi_s(\xi)
\end{equation}
for some smooth function $\varphi_s$. Hence, the Fourier transform of the integrable function $\tilde{u}_s$ is not Hölder continuous of any order $\alpha>s$.
If we want a Fourier transform that is not Hölder continuous of any order, one can take a cut-off function $\chi \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ with $\chi =1$ on the ball $B_1(0)$ and consider the integrable function $v_s := \tilde{u}_s-\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\chi \varphi_s)$. Then, it holds that $\mathcal{F}(v_s)(\xi)=|\xi|^s$ for all $|\xi| \leq 1$, and by defining
\begin{equation}
f:= \sum_{j=2}^{\infty} \frac{v_{1/j}}{2^j\|v_{1/j}\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)}} \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d),
\end{equation}
we get that
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}(f)(\xi) = \sum_{j=2}^\infty \frac{1}{2^j\|v_{1/j}\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)}}|\xi|^{1/j} \quad \text{for all $|\xi|\leq 1$},
\end{equation}
which is not Hölder continuous of any order.
